# Why does Ember set by reference rather than by value?

Tags: ember.js, set

Ran into a strange behavior in Ember (1.0.0rc6) that I was hoping someone could explain. In the map loop, I originally wrote `@set('selected_date_range', date_range)` assuming that a copy of `date_range` would be stored in `selected_date_range`. However, that is not the case. A reference to `date_range` was stored instead so that -- on subsequent executions of the code when a match is not found -- the original `date_range` would be overwritten by the "custom" date range.

```
 selectDateRange: (date_range_value) ->
    # determine if passed in date range is in supported date range array
    isSupported = @get('supported_date_ranges').map((date_range) =>
      supported = if date_range_value is date_range.value
        # date_range must be copied otherwise future changes to
        # selected_date_range will modify the supported_date_ranges array. wtf.
        @set('selected_date_range', Ember.copy(date_range))
        true
      else
        false
      return supported
    ).reduce (memo, next) -> memo or next
    # date range value is not in supported array so it is custom
    unless isSupported
      @set('selected_date_range.value', date_range_value)
      @set('selected_date_range.title', 'Custom')
      @set('selected_date_range.name', 'custom')
```

Why would Ember set by reference -- essentially create a computed alias -- rather than set by value?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess:

```
@set('selected_date_range', Ember.copy(date_range, true))
```

This should create a deep copy of the `date_range` object.

Comment: sorry, the code that I posted works. It was broken when I first tried `@set('selected_date_range', date_range)` which seemed like it should set `selected_date_range` to a copy of `date_range` and not a pointer to `date_range`.